# Firebase - JS Query - Get a Node where the Child value has a Child with value=xxx

Tags: javascript, firebase

I ran into a little problem with my firebase queries.
I want to get all series with episodes that i haven't watched yet. At the moment i load them all from firebase and use the filter function in JavaScript. But i would like to minimize the Data Download from firebase a bit.

So i only want the get the series that match this dummycode criteria:

```
ref("series").orderByChild("seasons/*/episodes/*/episodeWatched").equalTo(false)
```

This is a small output of my structure in firebase

```
series >
    <unique series id>
        seriesName: string
        seasons >
            seasonCount: number
            <season nummer>
                episodes >
                    <episode number>
                        episodeName: string
                        episodeWatched: boolean
                        episodeAirDate: Date
```

a more "real" exampel would be:

```
{ series: 
    [{ 123456: 
        { seriesName: "Mr Robot", 
          seasonCount: 3,
          seasons:
            [{ 0: episodeCount: 10,
                 episodes:
                   [{ 0:
                        { episodeName: "Eps1.0_hellofriend.mov",
                          episodeWatched: true,
                          episodeAirDate: 27-05-2015 }
                    { 1:
                        { episodeName: "Eps1.1_ones-and-zer0es.mpeg",
                          episodeWatched: false,
                          episodeAirDate: 01-07-2015 }
                   ...
                   }]
            ...
            }]
        }                            
   }]
}
```

I have a problem with this "wildcards" in my dummycode above, i get only the values of specific nodes, and i can't concat the "orderByChild" function.

If i could concat the function, my aproach to this would be like:

```
ref("series").orderByChild("seasons").orderByChild("episodes").orderByChild("episodeWatched").equalTo(false)
```

At the moment i tried several things with wildcards or anything like that, the only thing that works at the moment is:

```
ref("series").orderByChild("seasons/0/episodes/0/episodeWatched").equalTo(false)
```

but this only checks: is the first episode of the first season checked.

Did anyone had this problem yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is one of those times you duplicate / restructure your db to optimize for reads.

user/uid/notWatched: {
  "showId_seasonId_epId": true
}

Comment: I restructured some data, i have another flag at the root of the series to show if its completly watched or not. Thanks for this "Think"-direction.